# cucumber option dryrun=true is skipping scenario

Tags: cucumber-java

package runnerFile;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(

```
    features= {"src/test/resources/features"},glue= {"stepDefination"},
            dryRun=false,
    monochrome=true,strict=true


    )
```

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

}

Comment: Feature file:Feature: Login Action
 
Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
 Given User is on Home Page
 When User Navigate to LogIn Page
 And User enters UserName and Password
 Then Message displayed Login Successfully
 
Scenario: Successful LogOut
 When User LogOut from the Application
 Then Message displayed LogOut Successfully

Comment: What is your question?